# how to create identifier on the fly

Tags: java, android

I my code, I have:

```
    public Bitmap loadIMG(Context context) {
        File pfile = getIMGPathFile(context);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (pfile.exists()) {
            try {
                //noinspection IOStreamConstructor
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(pfile));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String from = String.format(FILE_PROD_PREFIX + Consts.FILE_NUMERIC_FORMAT, mId);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), context.getResources().getIdentifier(from, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

But I get a warning:

> Use of this function is discouraged because resource reflection makes
> it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification
> of code. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier
> (e.g. `R.foo.bar`) than by name (e.g. `getIdentifier("bar", "foo", null)`).

How can I modify my code with a minimum of side effects please?

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with this bitmap?  Do you actually need the bitmap, or is the Drawable sufficient?  If you' just need the drawable, the entire code is:

```
context.getDrawable(R.id.filename);
```

There is almost NEVER a good reason to use decodeResources.  Resources are preloaded into memory for fast access-  they're already decoded.  So you can just use them as a drawable.  Generally if you're trying to load one of several drawables like you seem to by creating a parameterized path, you should be using assets instead of resources.

Comment: I understand well, and I feared this answer.
The app is certainly very poorly designed from the start. It was my first. And only my wife and I use it. So I'm not going to review its deep functioning for a warning. If there is no simple solution, it will stay like this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case, I'd say it's probably not worth fixing it.  It is a warning, not an error.  The code will work, it's just inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to have an array of identifiers, and use mId (or some other expression) as an index in that array:

```
static final int ids[] = {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,....};
...
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),ids[mId]);
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think it will be possible like that, see my other answer.